# how to bind data efficiently in listview

Tags: android

I'm using `ListView` to show content from a server database. I have some questions:

1. If the data set is so large (such as 2000 items) how can I bind it to `ListView` efficiently by using `BaseAdapter`?
2. If I want save the content in cache file, when the data is changed on the server, I must get the data from server again, then rewrite the cache file, but I think if data is large, rewriting the whole cache file is not efficient.
3. All the content I get from server of course is in JSON format. I save the data in a cache file, in order to use next time with out getting it from the server. Is saving the JSON data in a cache file the right approach? Is there another good solution? I want my `ListView` to be more efficient.

I need some help.

Comment: Consider lazy load, and load say 20 items at a time. This should improve the responsiveness of the app. And refreshing data in the list from every change on server is not a good idea in my opinion. Instead give user the option to refresh the list. And for the listview you don't need to cache the data usually, android's listview handles it for us.

Comment: but once there is no network .how to show the data in listview that u loaded last time ,even U exit app and open again.

Comment: in that case you might want to look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: yes I think so.i want know when get json from server. which one is better? one is using paging query and bind data by listview page  the other one is get all json and change it as json array then bind data by json array index.or have other good solution?

Comment: I think that option with paging is better, that way if user has slow connection it would still be usable. Perhaps External storage or SQLite db would be more suitable in this case. I did a similar app, that required offline functionality, what we did is we gave user the option to save data(save option per data item/set), so it could be accessed even when no network was available. It also saved memory space, as user could choose what data to save.

Comment: Very thanks for U suggest. i will consider that